# Can I make node.js Date always be in UTC/GMT?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone

My app runs on Linux servers, where the time is (naturally) set to UTC/GMT. However the app is developed on Mac desktops where the time is typically set to a local timezone.

I could change every `new Date()` in my code to run:

```
var date = new Date().getTime();
```

And thus ensure dates on the server are always GMT, but that seems inelegant.

I understand [previous versions of node used to always return UTC/GMT](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3044). Is there any way to bring this behavior back?

**Edit:** Removed adding timezone offset to getTime() per comments - since getTime() is already in UTC.

Comment: I think that old behavior was just the way the REPL code worked. You can always use the UTC APIs in your own code if you want.

Comment: @pointy is there any way to make UTC the default when `new Date()` is ran?

Comment: You can *always* get the UTC date from a Date instance. Other than keeping the underlying platform set with UTC as the local time zone, however, I don't know of a way to tell the JavaScript runtime (node) to do that for you.

Comment: `getTime()` will always return the ms since the epoch in UTC.  Adding the current time zone offset is never a good idea.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `TZ` configuration parameter of node.js as follows.

For bash (and related)

```
export TZ=UTC
```

For Powershell

```
$env:TC = 'UTC'
```

Then for both:

```
nodejs server/index.js
```

Comment: Great, thanks! One note, when running unit tests with Mocha that test dates, I needed to run it like `export TZ=UTC; mocha --recursive test`. Though `export TZ=utc` works to change the time zone to UTC, the CI box writes it uppercased as `UTC` —important if you do a date string assertion.

Answer (score 18):

From [the MDN docs on `Date#getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime):

> The value returned by the getTime method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Assuming you're storing dates/times as numbers (which I would recommend), `getTime` **is already UTC, always**.

Suppose your client then requests a date from the server. If the server provides the date as a *number*, the client can then do:

```
new Date(timestamp);
```

And it will be correctly adjusted to the local time on the client.

Of course, maybe I'm misunderstanding your problem. But I just want to point out that this...

```
new Date().getTime() + new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

...should never really make sense. It's taking a UTC-based time and then offsetting it further, in essence double-offsetting a time.