# Change browser timezone in cypress.io (Windows)

Tags: timezone, cypress

I'm currently writing a test in cypress.io to test a web app, and I need to test this in various time zones, so that I'm sure that I'm getting the correct date and time on the server.

I stumbled on this github case https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1043 that is still open, but someone said "Setting TZ=UTC worked for me." but I have no idea on how to set that setting, and even if it's possible to do it.

Thx.

Comment: I don't think that answer is specific to cypress.io.  For windows you can change it in powershell $env:TC = 'UTC' see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35888788/94598